# VIM select all matching patterns in one line

Tags: vim

Can anybody please help on my issue regarding VIM?
This is my scenario:

```
The red redfox02animal jump over the blue reddog01animal.
```

I tried this search patten

```
/red.*[0-9]
```

but the result is "redfox02animal jump over the blue reddog01". What I want are two matched "redfox02" and "redfox01"

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Use `/red.\{-}[0-9]\+` instead of `/red.*[0-9]`, the former is non-greedy, while the latter (default) is [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the new knowledge

Comment: @FrancisPadron `{-}` matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible. http://vimregex.com/

Answer (score 2):

this should go too:

```
/red\D*\d\+
```

Note that this gives the same matches as Tobi's answer, the first match is:

```
red redfox02
```

if you just want to have `redfox02` and `reddog01` (there is no `redfox01` in your input, you cannot get it, as you stated in your question), you can try:

```
/red[^0-9 ]\d\+
```